# Time complexity to get average of large data set using subsets

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

Say you're given a large set of numbers (size n) and asked to compute the average of the data. You only have enough space and memory for c numbers at one time. What is the run-time complexity of this data?

Comment: surely its O(n) as it only requires one pass?

Comment: perhaps you mean return the number closest to the mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute an average for the whole dataset, the complexity would be O(n). Consider the following algorithm:

```
set sum = 0;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ // Loop n times
   add value of n to sum;
}
set average = sum / n;
```

Since we can disregard the two constant time operations, the main operation (adding value to sum) occurs n times.

In this particular example, you only have data for 'c' numbers at one time. For each individual group, you'll need a time complexity of O(c). However, this will not change your overall complexity, because ultimately you will be making n passes.

To provide a concrete example, consider the case n = 100 and c = 40, and your values are passed in an array. Your first loop would have 40 passes, the second another 40, and the third only twenty. Regardless, you have made 100 passes through the loop.

This assumes also that it is a constant time operation to get the second set of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is `O(n)`.

A basic (though not particularly stable) algorithm computes it iteratively as follows:

```
mean = 0
for n = 0,1,2,.. length(arr)-1
    mean = (mean*n + arr[n])/(n+1)
```

A variant of this algorithm can be used to parse the data from the array in sets of `c` numbers, but it is still linear in `n`.

### Ie, spelling out the seralization:

To spell it out, you can do this:

```
mean = 0
for m = 0, c, 2c, ..., arr_length -1
    sub_arr = request_sub_arr_between(m,min(m+c-1, total_length(arr)-1))
    for i = 0, 1, ..., length(sub_arr)
        n = m + i
        mean = (mean*n + sub_arr[i])/(n+1)
```

This is still `O(n)`, as we are only doing a bounded number of things for each `n`. In fact, the algorithm given at the top of this answer is a variant of this with `c=1`. If `sub_arr` is not kept in local memory, but `sub_arr[n]` is read at each step, then we are only storing 3 numbers at any step.

Comment: I don't think that is true, the answer is probably O(n log(n)), that is because you need to take into account that `you only have enough space for c number at a time`

Comment: See the edit below, this only stores `c + 4` numbers in memory at any one time (`mean, m, sub_arr (length c), i, n`). Of course I may be misinterpreting the question(?)